# DATE(timestamp) returning wrong month

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

Here is my query:

```
$chart_result = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                             FROM (SELECT DATE(timestamp) AS ts, 
                                          YEAR(timestamp) AS year, 
                                          MONTH(timestamp) AS month, 
                                          DAY(timestamp) AS day, 
                                          SUM(paymentgross) AS sales 
                                   FROM stats_ans_1 
                                   GROUP BY DATE(timestamp) DESC 
                                   LIMIT 10
                                  ) AS TBL 
                             GROUP BY ts");
```

and here is the timestamp:

```
2012-09-12 19:45:23
```

MONTH(timestamp) is absolutely determined that the timestamp is in October not September - which is obviously wrong. Have mercy on my poor brain cells!

Comment: [Works fine](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51e74/1)

Comment: how do I get it to return the right month

Comment: You should avoid using `mysql_query` in new applications. `mysqli` is nearly as easy to use and also provides [SQL placeholder](http://bobby-tables.com/php) functionality to ensure data safety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function to return month in string format:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2012-09-12 19:45:23', '%M') AS `month`;
```

Also you don't need to use `GROUP BY` twice, try this query:

```
SELECT DATE(timestamp) AS ts,
       YEAR(timestamp) AS year,
       MONTH(timestamp) AS month,
       DAY(timestamp) AS day,
       SUM(paymentgross) AS sales
FROM stats_ans_1
GROUP BY DATE(timestamp) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```